# Formatting a Numbers in DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

Can someone please help me to format just numbers in a data frame to "int" and "comma"? I tried doing the same and got an error message mentioned below.

Error: int() argument must be string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'DataFrame'

```
import pandas as pd

data1 = {'Header':['L1','L2','L3'], 'Val1':[float(1000.2),float(2000.40),float(300.55)],
         'Val2':[float(4000.3),float(500.00),float(60000.55)]}
```

The expected output is mentioned below.

| Header | Val1 | Val2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| L1 | 1,000 | 4,000 |
| L2 | 2,000 | 500 |
| L3 | 301 | 60,001 |

Comment: *format just numbers in a data frame to "int" and "comma"?* What do you mean? Can you provide an example of what you expect with your sample, please?

Comment: @Corralien I have updated the question with the expected output. Thanks

Comment: @Corralien Thanks for the quick response, I don't want to just Display it, I am exporting this table to PDF and hence I need to format it accordingly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to display your dataframe but not change the internal format, you can use:

```
with pd.option_context('display.float_format', '{:,.0f}'.format):
    print(df)

# Output
  Header  Val1   Val2
0     L1 1,000  4,000
1     L2 2,000    500
2     L3   301 60,001
```

Or for the current session without `ContextManager`:

```
pd.set_option('display.float_format', '{:,.0f}'.format)
print(df)

# Output
  Header  Val1   Val2
0     L1 1,000  4,000
1     L2 2,000    500
2     L3   301 60,001
```

**Edit**

There are many ways to export your table, use the `styler` or convert numbers as string. One solution:

```
cols = df.select_dtypes('number').columns
df[cols] = df[cols].map(lambda x: f'{x:,.0f}')
print(df)

# Output
  Header   Val1    Val2
0     L1  1,000   4,000
1     L2  2,000     500
2     L3    301  60,001
```

**PandaKim's comment**: Use `map` if you have `Pandas>=2.1.0` else replace `map` with `applymap` for older versions of Pandas. [`applymap`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) is now deprecated:

> Deprecated since version 2.1.0: DataFrame.applymap has been deprecated. Use DataFrame.map instead.

Another way to export using [`to_markdown`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_markdown.html) or [`to_string`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_string.html) or [`to_latex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_latex.html):

```
>>> print(df.to_markdown(floatfmt=",.0f"))
|    | Header   |   Val1 |   Val2 |
|---:|:---------|-------:|-------:|
|  0 | L1       |  1,000 |  4,000 |
|  1 | L2       |  2,000 |    500 |
|  2 | L3       |    301 | 60,001 |

>>> print(df.to_string(float_format='{:,.0f}'.format))
  Header  Val1   Val2
0     L1 1,000  4,000
1     L2 2,000    500
2     L3   301 60,001

>>> print(df.to_latex(float_format='{:,.0f}'.format))
\begin{tabular}{llrr}
\toprule
 & Header & Val1 & Val2 \\
\midrule
0 & L1 & 1,000 & 4,000 \\
1 & L2 & 2,000 & 500 \\
2 & L3 & 301 & 60,001 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, I don't want to just Display, I am exporting this table to pdf and hence I need to format it accordingly.

Comment: I updated my answer. Do you need another way to export your data? :-)

Comment: It's a good answer. However, it seems that there might be a Pandas version issue. if questioner doesn't have 2.1.0+, and an error occurs in the code of the third answer,  use the `applymap` function instead of `map` function in the third answer.

Comment: @PandaKim. Thanks for letting me know, I forgot about that